# Twitter bootstrap: center button toolbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="btn-toolbar">
      <!-- buttons go here -->
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to center my button toolbar without using offset?

I tried applying "margin: 0 auto;" to my toolbar div but this did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rx9Y2/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="btn-toolbar">
          <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn">1</button>
              <button class="btn">2</button>
              <button class="btn">3</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn">1</button>
              <button class="btn">2</button>
              <button class="btn">3</button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

---

```
.btn-toolbar{
  text-align: center;
}​
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use inline css and it work for me.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" style="justify-content: center; display: flex;" >
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try add "center" attribute on row class on bootstrap 3.
like

`<div class="row center"> 
....
</div>`